# Nivo slider: first img appears twice???- i only want it once

Tags: html, image, nivo-slider

:) 
i use nivo slider and all works pretty fine now. the only issue i have is that as soon as i click on the video to open the img slider, the first img appears twice. 
I only want to see the img once. I wonder weather the img appears twice becouse it appears when the slider openes and then it is called as the first img. how do i then call the secound img to come next? 
thx a lot for helping.. 
this is the code i m talking about.

```
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
    <a title="Image 1"href="Figuren-Bilder/Marilyn/1.jpg" data-lightbox-gallery="galleryvid1">
    <video class="thumbnail img-responsive active" src="Figuren-Filme/Marilyn.webm" id="id0" width="320" onMouseOver="this.play()" onMouseOut="this.pause()" muted loop >
    </video>
    <div class=""><p>Marilyn, "Der Tod und das Mädchen", Bronzeguss, XX cm</p></a></div>
    <a title="Image 2"href="Figuren-Bilder/Marilyn/1.jpg" class="gallery-thumb-hidden" data-lightbox-gallery="galleryvid1"></a>
    <a title="Image 3"href="Figuren-Bilder/Marilyn/1.jpg" class="gallery-thumb-hidden" data-lightbox-gallery="galleryvid1"></a>
    <a title="Image 4"href="Figuren-Bilder/Marilyn/1.jpg" class="gallery-thumb-hidden" data-lightbox-gallery="galleryvid1"></a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Probably to do with the invalid HTML. You have a closing `div` outside your `a` when it should be inside. Your browser will try to correct this possibly giving unexpected results

Comment: oh man thx a lot, you solved it.. I hate such bugs..
I would like to give you a hook so it says it s solved but i cant.. :(

Comment: I'll add it as an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a mistake in your markup. You are closing a `div` outside an `a` when it is opened inside.

Most browsers will try to correct invalid HTML. This can lead to unexpected result like you are seeing with your slider.

Correct markup should be:

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
    <a title="Image 1"href="Figuren-Bilder/Marilyn/1.jpg" data-lightbox-gallery="galleryvid1">
        <video class="thumbnail img-responsive active" src="Figuren-Filme/Marilyn.webm" id="id0" width="320" onMouseOver="this.play()" onMouseOut="this.pause()" muted loop ></video>
        <div class="">
            <p>Marilyn, "Der Tod und das Mädchen", Bronzeguss, XX cm</p>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a title="Image 2"href="Figuren-Bilder/Marilyn/1.jpg" class="gallery-thumb-hidden" data-lightbox-gallery="galleryvid1"></a>
    <a title="Image 3"href="Figuren-Bilder/Marilyn/1.jpg" class="gallery-thumb-hidden" data-lightbox-gallery="galleryvid1"></a>
    <a title="Image 4"href="Figuren-Bilder/Marilyn/1.jpg" class="gallery-thumb-hidden" data-lightbox-gallery="galleryvid1"></a>
</div>
```